# GetColumnLabel name and run ajax function - google viz datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization, googlevis

Here I have google visualisation DataTable: [image]

So i have this code:

```
function drawTroskovnik() {


  // Create and populate the data table.
  var JSONObject = $.ajax({
    url: 'getTroskovnik.php', // make this url point to the data file
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{id_akt:ajdi},
        async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    }).responseText;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONObject, 0.5);

for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    for (var x = 1, maxcols = data.getNumberOfColumns(); x < maxcols; x++) {

      data.setValue(y, x, '<input id="costRedovi" class="form-control" value="'+data.getValue(y,x)+'">');
    }
} 
 for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {

      data.setValue(y, 0, '<input class="span2 form-control" id="pocetak1" size="16" type="text" value="'+data.getValue(y,0)+'" readonly>');

} 


        data.addColumn('string', 'Kontrole');
        for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
        var mc= data.getNumberOfColumns()-1;
data.setValue(y, mc, '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update" href="#" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Details</a>');

        }
new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function () {
            var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
            //HOW TO GET LABEL of COLUMN an DATE from row so to use it in ajax submit
     $( "#costRedovi" ).focusout(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { columnName:HOW_to_get_column_name,datum:How_to_get_date_from_row_where_is_selected_cell?}, 
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);   
            },  
        });
  })
                        }
        });
    });
  // Create and draw the visualization.
  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tpltroskovnik'));
  visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true, cssClassNames: 'nn' }});
}
```

What I need to do?
Now I have each cell value into input field, so I can change it. I want on `.focusout` to run `.ajax` function to `update` data in database, but to do this I need to `get Column Label Name and date` (as you can see on photo - date is a '0' position in row...)

How I can get Column Label Name and date for cell which is on focusout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very easy to solve this problem, so I get columnLabel on new better way:

```
for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    for (var x = 1, maxcols = data.getNumberOfColumns(); x < maxcols; x++) {

      data.setValue(y, x, '<input id="costRedovi" kol="'+ data.getColumnLabel(x) +'" class="form-control" value="'+data.getValue(y,x)+'">');
    }
}
```

so the solution was: data.getColumnLabel(x), now every input has attribute `kol` and now is easy to run ajax code when datatable is ready.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is call `getValue` on the data you've put in the table in the selection handler. The relevant code is:

```
        var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
        console.log(data.getValue(row,0));
```

Check out this fiddle, and let me know if you have more questions:

http://jsfiddle.net/WTb8H/

Comment: :) ok, I know that, but if you see my question, I need when I click on table cell i need to get column label Name of that cell and date from row, so now I have date but I dont have column label name...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WTb8H/1/, also when I click once and after that one more i get error, see in console

Comment: Okay, two things: the selection is sticky, so the second time you select the same row, it acts as an unselect option. Secondly, currently the table view doesn't send the column. Let me think about how to get it....

Comment: can you get it with getColumnLabel from googel viz API ?

Comment: so what if I have more columns ,,, etc. 5 columns ... also can you type all code in one jsfiddle?

Comment: The `makeDiv` function in the fiddle does it for you -- you can have a million columns.

Comment: ok, thanks ,can you copy all in one jsfiddle - var clickedColumn = ? and var dateFromRow = ???

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but I can't. I doubt jsfiddle will do all the ajax correctly. :) Frankly, all you need to do is copy the `makeDiv` functionality, and plop the `onmousedown` code when you make all the `div`s in your two `for` loops.

Comment: this is not exactly what i looking for... i need to work with my code. but thanks for help